# Drop down of auto values country/state/city WooCommerce storefront

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, state, checkout

I am looking for a drop down of country/state/city. I am getting country state auto populated, but cities are not going through well. By default, I am able to get the countries.

```
// State-Country additions

/**
 * Code goes in functions.php or a custom plugin.
 */

add_filter('woocommerce_states', 'SA_woocommerce_states');

function SA_woocommerce_states($states) {
    $states['ZA'] = array(
        'EC' => __('Eastern Cape', 'woocommerce'),
    );
    return $states;
}

// Change "city" checkout billing and shipping fields to a dropdown

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'override_checkout_city_fields');

function override_checkout_city_fields($fields) {

    // Define here in the array your desired cities (Here an example of cities)
    $option_cities = array(
        '' => __('Select your city'),
        'a' => 'a',
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['options'] = $option_cities;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['options'] = $option_cities;

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: This is not a complete example, so we cannot reproduce your problem easily. Please elaborate on what your code does and what you expect instead.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your actual code you are replacing all existing states of "South Africa" (ZA) by one state. So you are getting something like:

[image]

To add this state you should need to change your code a little bit this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_states', 'sa_woocommerce_states');
add_filter('woocommerce_countries_allowed_country_states', 'sa_woocommerce_states');

function SA_woocommerce_states( $states ) {
    $states['ZA']['EC'] = __('Eastern Cape', 'woocommerce');
    return $states;
}
```

The code goes in the *function.php* file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works. You will get that instead this time:

[image]

Now to get the cities auto populated you should use this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'override_checkout_city_fields', 10, 1 );
function override_checkout_city_fields($fields) {

    // Define here in the array your desired cities (Here an example of cities)
    $option_cities = array(
        '' => __( 'Select your city' ),
        'a' => 'a',
    );

    $fields['city']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['city']['options'] = $option_cities;

    return $fields;
}
```

The code goes in the *function.php* file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

It was tested ad worked…

<sub>But you will not get cities by states as this is a real development and too broad for Stack Overflow</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your response.i am able to get states but not cities which for example is a.

Comment: @Ferna Yes this is too broad and a real development… You should create a plugin that extends WC_Countries Class and WC_Checkout Class too… You should better hire a developer as you will not get this for free anywhere on the net. May be you can check if plugins exits… Remember that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service. That said good luck to you

Comment: i am here to learn and if its broad will take into notice.Thanks